# Eliminar registro sin recargar la pagina Ajax Mysql php

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

**El registro se elimina correctamente de la base de datos, pero no se muestra el cambio en pantalla, la salida de mis datos es a través de una tabla.**

```html
**PHP donde se muestran los datos **
<?php

$consulta2 = "SELECT ...
?>
      <script>
      function objetoAjax(){
          var xmlhttp=false;
          try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (e) {
          try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
          }
        }
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          return xmlhttp;
        }
function eliminarDato(IDDefectos_por_Origen,NombreProyecto,IDProyectoSpiraTest){
   //donde se mostrará el resultado de la eliminacion
    //$("#resultado").show();//muestra el div
   divResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
   //usaremos un cuadro de confirmacion
   var eliminar = confirm("De verdad desea eliminar este dato?")
   if (eliminar) {
   //instanciamos el objetoAjax
   ajax=objetoAjax();
   //uso del medotod GET
   //indicamos el archivo que realizará el proceso de eliminación
   //junto con un valor que representa el id del empleado
   ajax.open("GET", "../control/EliminarD_Origen.php?IDDefectos_por_Origen="+IDDefectos_por_Origen+"&NombreProyecto="+NombreProyecto+"&IDProyectoSpiraTest="+IDProyectoSpiraTest);
   ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (ajax.readyState==4) {
   //mostrar resultados en esta capa
   divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
    }
   }
   //como hacemos uso del metodo GET
   //colocamos null
   ajax.send(null)
   }
}
      </script>
  <div id="tabla1">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="cabecera">
      <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>ID-ST</td>
        <td>Proyecto</td>
        <td>Origen</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Eliminar</td>
      </tr>
       <?php while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $IDDefectos_por_Origen = $fila['IDDefectos_por_Origen']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['IDProyectoSpiraTest']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['NombreProyecto']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['Origen']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['TotalDefectos']; ?></td>
        <td><a onclick="eliminarDato('<?php echo $fila['IDDefectos_por_Origen']; ?>');" id="<?php echo $IDDefectos_por_Origen . '' . $NombreProyecto . '' . $IDProyectoSpiraTest; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php }?>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
**PHP edonde se ejecuta la sentencia DELETE**
<?php
include_once "../clase/conexion.php";
$obj                   = new conectar();
$conexion              = $obj->conexion();
$IDDefectos_por_Origen = $_GET['IDDefectos_por_Origen'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM defectos_por_origen WHERE IDDefectos_por_Origen='$IDDefectos_por_Origen'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
if ($sql) {
    echo 'ID,' . $IDDefectos_por_Origen = $_GET['IDDefectos_por_Origen'] . ' eliminado correctamente';
}
```

Comment: ¿Por casualidad usas jQuery o no? ¿Tienes en tu HTML un `<div>` cuyo `id` es `resultado` y dicho id no se repite en ningún otro elemento?

Comment: creo que te faltarian dos cosas: 1.- la funcion php que borra el registro debe devolverte un valor (normalmente, un array de indices borrados en json). 2.- el objetoAjax debe recibir esos datos del json, evaluarlos y por javascript borrar registro en tu plantilla (en funcion de esos datos evaluados).

Comment: La manera de notar el cambio es actualizando la pagina en el ajax pone lo siguiente location.href= "tupagina";

Comment: El usuario dice "Sin recargar la página" por eso comenta que utiliza ajax

Comment: Yo lo que haría es crear una función de carga principal de datos un ajax que obtenga los datos siempre, después como ya tienes la función de eliminar datos cuando la mandas llamar al final de la función llamo por defecto a la función que me carga los datos. Slds